# npm: meaning of main attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

`npm init` will generate a file named `package.json`. Here is the content:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
   ....
}
```

I read on this [package.json doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

> The main field is a module ID
>   that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, if your
>   package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does
>   require("foo"), then your main module's exports object will be
>   returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
>   often not much else.

I don't really understand this. Because in my project and in some projects I have downloaded, it looks like this field is no effect. I change the file name, example: `"main": "temp.js"` and app still runs normal.

Comment: It depends on each particular module. You may provide any, to have a look and figure out. Also it depends on how are you importing the module.

Comment: Are you using `require("./my-webpack-tut")` to run your app? Or are you running it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Node algorithm pseudocode used to resolve one module can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

**package.json :: main** - is useful if you want to create a module that can be resolved by its [folder](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). This will be a file that references the entire library provided by the module.

In your case this will be used when other module will require your module that you are building right now.

For example the well known [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) can have a build holding the entire library which can be referenced like `require('lodash')`. This works because the [`package.json`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/package.json) file has `"main: "lodash.js"`. In many cases this might not be a good idea because you might need only a portion of this library. So instead, one can use the core build and reference in addition other files or builds as deem necessary.

As another example, if you have module `libraryA` in a folder named `./libraryA` with `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "libraryA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./lib/entireMegaHugeLibraryA.js",
   ....
}
```

And a module `libraryB` in a folder named `./libraryB`. Then you can require `libraryA` by doing `require('../libraryA')`. This will resolve to `../libraryA/lib/entireMegaHugeLibraryA.js`.

Now if you analyze the [algorithm pseudocode](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) you are found yourself at line `a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.`.